# Estimate Δf using the Linear Approximation and use a calculator to compute the error.

Tags: calculus

Estimate Δf using the Linear Approximation and use a calculator to compute the error. 
$f(x)= \sqrt{3+x}$

$a=6$

$Δx= 0.5$

$Δf \approx \frac{1}{12}$

^ I got this part, just take the derivative.

With these calculations, we have determined that the square root of _____

^I was thinking it was the $\sqrt9$, but that is incorrect

is approximately _____

^obviously thought this was $3$

The error in Linear Approximation is: _____

^Went through the whole process of trying to find the approximation, ended up with a $negative$ number though $-107.38\%$

[Note: This is not asking for relative error or percent error.]

My main struggle is trying to understand what they are asking for?
Any ideas?

Comment: I've no idea what your first few lines mean.

Comment: I was hoping I wasn't the only one.

Comment: Are you sure the question states exactly that? What is $a$?

Comment: Maybe you're supposed to find $\sqrt{9.5} using linear approximation and then determine the error.

Comment: @Neal: That's what I would guess also.

Comment: a = where f is differentiable at x

Comment: Your last comment makes no sense. $a$ was set to be equal to $6$ in your question, so it cannot be where $f$ is differentiable, since $f$ is differentiable at **every real number** bigger than $-3$.

Comment: @Neal where do you get $\sqrt{9.5}$ ? this is correct, I'm just wondering.

Comment: @pewpew Writing homework problems like this. The idea is usually to find the value of $f$ near an "easy" value. Here, we know what $\sqrt{9}$ is and we can find the derivative at $9$, so we can use linear approximation to estimate square roots of numbers close to $9$. In this case, I guessed, $\sqrt{9.5}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\quad{f(X+\Delta x) \sim f(x) +\Delta x .f'(x)\\f(x)=\sqrt{3+x},f'(x)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3+x}}\\\to\\f(6+.5)\sim f(6) +.5 \frac{1}{2\sqrt{9}}=3+0.5*\frac{1}{6}=3+\frac{1}{12}$$
now
 $$f(6+\Delta x)-f(6)\sim \frac{1}{12}=0.083333333...}$$

without approximation $$\sqrt{3+6+0.5}-\sqrt{3+6}=0.0822070014844...$$